# How Can get this function to calculate float number e.g. 2.8 - 3.2 = -0.40000000000000036 instead of -0.4

Tags: javascript

HTML

```js
$(function() {
  $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", sum);

  function sum() {
    $("#subt").val(
      Number($("#num1").val()) -
      Number($("#num2").val())
    );
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="num1">
<input type="number" id="num2">
<input type="number" id="subt" readonly="">
```

Comment: See [Is floating point mathbroken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588019#588019), which this duplicates. For exhaustive details see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: `<input type="number" id="" readonly="">` seems to be missing the ID it needs